# Python: Drop nulls and duplicates for multiple condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and after lots of research and testing I still can't work this one out.

I am trying to remove nulls and duplicates on certain conditions, essentially I should be left with unique 'ID'. I am able to use .duplicated then .drop_duplicates and .dropna to drop the relevant rows for a subset of my dataframe but I can't work out how to put it all together on the original dataframe without removing rows I want to keep.

I would also like to keep all the dropped records in a separate dataframe but have not come accross how this possible.

Conditions;

- Remove all duplicates (keep=False) when 'ID' is duplicated and 'type' is unique
- Remove null 'code' values only when 'ID' and 'type' are duplicated
- Remove duplicates (keep='first') when 'ID' and 'type' are duplicated and 'code' is unique

Dataframe;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','code','type'])
df.ID = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,7,7]
df.code = ['a',np.nan,'b','c','d','d','a',np.nan,'e','f','g',np.nan]
df.type = ['type1','type1','type2','type2','type1','type2','type3','type1','type1','type2','type1','type2']

    ID  code    type
0   1   a   type1
1   1   NaN type1
2   2   b   type2
3   2   c   type2
4   3   d   type1
5   3   d   type2
6   4   a   type3
7   5   NaN type1
8   6   e   type1
9   6   f   type2
10  7   g   type1
11  7   NaN type2
```

The resulting dataframe should look like;

```
    ID  code    type
0   1   a   type1
1   2   b   type2
2   4   a   type3
3   5   NaN type1
```

At the moment this is what I am doing to get the right result but I feel like there is a better way.

```
df_unique = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'],keep=False)

df_dupe = df[df.duplicated(['ID','type'],keep=False)]

df_dupe2 = df_dupe.dropna(subset=['code']).drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','type'])

df_final = pd.concat([df_unique,df_dupe2]).sort_values('ID')
```

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please reconcile this statement: "*I still can't work this one out*" with this statement: "*this is what I am doing to get the right result*". Are you able to get the expected result or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain mask with `&` for bitwise `AND`, `|` for bitwise `OR` and `~` for inverse:

```
m1 = df.duplicated(subset=['ID'],keep=False)
m2 = df.duplicated(['ID','type'],keep=False) 
m3 = df.duplicated(['ID','type']) 
m4 = df['code'].notna()

df = df[~m1 | (m2 & ~m3 & m4)].sort_values('ID')
print (df)
   ID code   type
0   1    a  type1
2   2    b  type2
6   4    a  type3
7   5  NaN  type1
```